# Trigger add record when delete happened

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Im new with sql. please collect my answer. I have 2 tables.

1. Product [productID, name, qtyAvailable]
2. productSale [productSaleID,productID, qtySold]

   CREATE TRIGGER Product AFTER DELETE ON `product` FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   update product.qtyavailable = productsale.qtySold - old.productsale.qtySold 
   END;

I need to add qtySold while qtyavailable decrease at same time....

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger - should this trigger be on productsale? Your design looks wrong do you have a table which holds sales transactions by date (and other useful information)?

Answer (score 1):

i would like to suggest 2 triggers 
one will be the before delete trigger,

```
CREATE TRIGGER Product before DELETE ON product FOR EACH ROW BEGIN update product.qtyavailable = productsale.qtySold - old.productsale.qtySold END;
```

another will be after trigger to add qtySold when qtyavailable decrease at same time..

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Product after DELETE ON product FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
//logic  END;
```